# Rails Error: "\xE4" followed by "l" on UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8

When I load css or js files on rails 4.2.6 with the link tags ***javascript_include_tag*** and ***stylesheet_link_tag*** I get the error:

**Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError at /app
"\xE4" followed by "l" on UTF-8**

I never saw this error before. And when I load these same files with the html script like:

```
<script src="/assets/app/functions.js"></script>
```

Then it works.

my **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolink__s EDITED
//= require__tree .  EDITED
```

Someone had this problem before?

Thanks!

Comment: It turns out your files are `Latin-1` aka `ISO-8856-1` encoded, while Ruby expects it to be `UTF-8`.

Comment: Can you show your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: Just edited the text to show the application.js

Comment: I just edited the apllication,js to jsut load the rails jquery files: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs and still got the error, even with just rails js

Comment: Can you copy/paste your Gemfile and tell me do you use Supersized jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, since you do not seem to understand the short explanation in comments, I will put this as an answer.

```
puts "\xE4".force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
#⇒ ä
```

That said, either one (or many) of your stylesheets, or one (or many) of your javascripts are stored in `ISO-8859-1` encoding. Ruby tries to read everything in `UTF-8` by default. You should find the file that causes problems, open it in any editor and save back in `UTF-8` encoding.

You might also do the bulk update with smth like

```
Dir['*/**/*.js', '*/**/*.css'].each do |f|
  File.write f, File.read(f).force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
end
```

Please aware that the bulk update might cause the opposite problem, if any of files contained valid utf-8.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. I tried to open with sublime text and save all files with utf-8 "File > Save with encoding > utf-8". But did not work =/

Comment: @mudasobwa We don't really know that the encoding is ISO-8859-1. It could be any one of the various ISO-8859-x or Windows-12xx encodings in which `ä` is 0xE4, or in fact any encoding in which 0xE4 is a valid byte, although ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1253 are the likeliest candidates. The only thing we can be sure of is that it's *not* UTF-8.

Comment: @Jordan indeed, but I bet there is likely not heavy usage of such symbols and simplest action should do the trick.

Comment: @FernandoAureliano **what** did you try to open and save?